# fill between two lines lacking common x values

Tags: python, matplotlib, fill

I wish to fill regions between two lines in Python 3x (I mostly work in v3.7 presently) using data series that share a common scale, but lack mutual x-values.

'fill_between' would be handy but requires common x values for the two y-series
[matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html)
[matplotlib demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html)

data follows:

```
x1 = [0.0, 3.2, 10.2, 15.4, 19.9, 24.2, 27.7, 33.9, 50.7, 67.9, 83.7, 102.0, 105.8, 119.4, 129.3, 140.3, 146.0, 150.2, 158.3, 166.7, 168.6, 171.7, 173.5, 175.3, 184.1, 203.7, 220.2, 221.8, 226.8, 231.9]
y1 = [99.95, 99.99, 100.11, 99.59, 98.24, 98.5, 99.21, 99.46, 99.35, 99.18, 98.71, 98.26, 97.92, 97.92, 98.02, 97.63, 97.63, 98.49, 99.17, 98.85, 97.35, 97.43, 98.66, 99.36, 99.14, 99.08, 99.25, 98.74, 98.82, 99.73]
x2 = [-1.5, 0.1, 4.1, 6.8, 7.4, 7.8, 11.5, 18.4, 25.2, 37.8, 46.3, 54.7, 59.7, 66.0, 75.1, 77.3, 91.4, 109.6, 122.5, 127.4, 133.2, 134.5, 138.3, 141.6, 145.1, 153.0, 153.7, 158.8, 162.8, 166.0, 167.2, 167.9, 172.7, 173.2, 175.0, 178.9, 183.0, 190.6, 199.5, 207.3, 210.5, 215.6, 222.2, 224.5, 227.7, 231.9]
y2 = [100.12, 100.16, 100.27, 100.26, 98.85, 98.22, 98.08, 98.2, 99.15, 99.41, 99.27, 98.88, 98.36, 98.24, 98.48, 99.42, 99.37, 99.13, 99.16, 99.1, 98.66, 98.31, 98.16, 98.46, 98.06, 97.96, 98.45, 99.32, 99.3, 99.23, 98.42, 97.62, 98.02, 98.74, 99.47, 99.24, 99.22, 99.12, 99.17, 99.1, 98.91, 99.16, 98.91, 98.82, 99.02, 99.78]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(14,6))

ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(x1,y1,c='blue')
ax.plot(x2,y2,c='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: two x,y line series]

if I try to fill between, I get a ValueError (because the series are different shapes). For example:

```
ax.fill_between(x1,y1,y2)
```

returns:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (30,)
> (46,)

I'm unable to simply express my y values in terms of a common x like:
[approach2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417496/matplotlib-fill-between-multiple-lines)

this approach seems a bit of a hack by overplotting a mask and won't work for my data with multiple reversals:
[approach3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643581/fill-area-between-two-lines-with-python)

It would seem that I need to intersect the two x-series and interpolate the missing y-values for each series respectively? or is there an easier way I'm missing?

Eventually, I'm looking to shade the regions differentially, e.g.:

```
ax.fill_between(x,y1,y2, interploate=True, where =(y1<y2),c="blue")
ax.fill_between(x,y1,y2, interploate=True, where =(y1>y2),c="red")
```

Comment: Your best bet is to interpolate one data set to the other. If you’re worried you could interpolate both lines to a highly sampled x variable, e.g. `x_new = np.linspace(min(x1, x2), max(x1, x2), len(x1) + len(x2))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a common x-axis by sorting the combined `x1` and `x2`. Then, you can interpolate `x1,y1` onto that new x-axis (and similar for `x2,y2`):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = [0.0, 3.2, 10.2, 15.4, 19.9, 24.2, 27.7, 33.9, 50.7, 67.9, 83.7, 102.0, 105.8, 119.4, 129.3, 140.3, 146.0, 150.2, 158.3, 166.7, 168.6, 171.7, 173.5, 175.3, 184.1, 203.7, 220.2, 221.8, 226.8, 231.9]
y1 = [99.95, 99.99, 100.11, 99.59, 98.24, 98.5, 99.21, 99.46, 99.35, 99.18, 98.71, 98.26, 97.92, 97.92, 98.02, 97.63, 97.63, 98.49, 99.17, 98.85, 97.35, 97.43, 98.66, 99.36, 99.14, 99.08, 99.25, 98.74, 98.82, 99.73]
x2 = [-1.5, 0.1, 4.1, 6.8, 7.4, 7.8, 11.5, 18.4, 25.2, 37.8, 46.3, 54.7, 59.7, 66.0, 75.1, 77.3, 91.4, 109.6, 122.5, 127.4, 133.2, 134.5, 138.3, 141.6, 145.1, 153.0, 153.7, 158.8, 162.8, 166.0, 167.2, 167.9, 172.7, 173.2, 175.0, 178.9, 183.0, 190.6, 199.5, 207.3, 210.5, 215.6, 222.2, 224.5, 227.7, 231.9]
y2 = [100.12, 100.16, 100.27, 100.26, 98.85, 98.22, 98.08, 98.2, 99.15, 99.41, 99.27, 98.88, 98.36, 98.24, 98.48, 99.42, 99.37, 99.13, 99.16, 99.1, 98.66, 98.31, 98.16, 98.46, 98.06, 97.96, 98.45, 99.32, 99.3, 99.23, 98.42, 97.62, 98.02, 98.74, 99.47, 99.24, 99.22, 99.12, 99.17, 99.1, 98.91, 99.16, 98.91, 98.82, 99.02, 99.78]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(14, 6))

ax.plot(x1, y1, c='dodgerblue')
ax.plot(x2, y2, c='crimson')

xfill = np.sort(np.concatenate([x1, x2]))
y1fill = np.interp(xfill, x1, y1)
y2fill = np.interp(xfill, x2, y2)
ax.fill_between(xfill, y1fill, y2fill, where=y1fill < y2fill, interpolate=True, color='dodgerblue', alpha=0.2)
ax.fill_between(xfill, y1fill, y2fill, where=y1fill > y2fill, interpolate=True, color='crimson', alpha=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Outstanding answer. Not only did you confirm the approach, but provided nice clean, (and most important for me) readable code. If I could up-vote twice, I would.  Cheers!

Comment: you are an artist, i like it PICASSO!