# Fill the areas between lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fill

I would like to fill two areas, the first one is bordered by all the four functions, the second is bordered by the f and g functions. As I know, to apply the fill_between() function, the y datas should be generated from the same x datas. I know that the problem could be simplified by generating the function with the same x datas but I would like to know how to fix this problem in this way (with different x datas).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x1=np.linspace(0, 3, 100)
x2=np.linspace(0.4, 2.6, 150)
x3=np.linspace(0, 1.6, 180)
x4=np.linspace(0, 3, 125)

f=np.exp(x1)
g=5*x2-1
l=-40*x3+10
t=3*x4+9
plt.plot(x1, f, label='f(x)=e^x')
plt.plot(x2, g, label='g(x)=5x-1')
plt.plot(x3, l, label='l(x)=-4x+10')
plt.plot(x4, t, label='t(x)=3x+9')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('y axis')
plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylim(0,)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried to use the plt.fill_between()-function.

Comment: Why can't you use the plt.fill_between function?

Comment: @mkrieger1  For `plt.fill_between()` to work properly, the curves need common x values. OP created reproducible code and data, while the real data is a bit more complicated.

Comment: See e.g. [fill between two lines lacking common x values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541222) for an example how two curves can be combined on a common x-axis.

Comment: Not only do the lack common x values, the x and y values of the intersections will probably also be necessary. Otherwise the usage of `plt.fill_between(x4,t,l,where= (l>=f))` will leave small blank places.

Answer (score 0):

To use plt.fill_between() your curves need common x values.
In this example you could solve this by rewriting your code to declare the x1,...,x4 variables.

```
x1=np.linspace(0, 3, 3000)
x2=np.linspace(0, 3, 3000)
x3=np.linspace(0, 3, 3000)
x4=np.linspace(0, 3, 3000)
```

After that you could use multiple plt.fill_between() methods to fill out the area.

```
plt.fill_between(x4,t,l,where= (l>f) & (t>l), alpha=0.3, color="C0")
plt.fill_between(x4,t,f,where= (t>f) & (l<f) & (f>g), alpha=0.3, color="C0")
plt.fill_between(x4,t,g,where= (t>g) & (f<g), alpha=0.3, color="C0")
```

[image: entire1] [image: zoomed2]

This unfortunately leaves some small but visible blank places. This is because the x,y lists don't include the exact intersection points which makes the `where=` clauses pick the closest point to the intersection condition is still true.